# How to safelycompare UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1 (latin1) in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding

This might be a stupid question, but nothing seems to be working for me:

I'm having to compare values between 2 columns on 2 different databases (which I don't have access to change the values).
The encoding in **db1** is UTF-8. 
The encoding in **db2** is latin1.

So, for example, these are the 2 values I'm comparing and should be the same in the comparison:

```
**db1_value** = 'Maranh&atilde;o'
**db2_value** = 'Maranhão';
```

They display exactly the same way using utf_encode, displaying is not the issue.
I'd like to compare the variable **db1_value** to the field **db2_value** in the db, so I'm using something very simple like this:

```
$query = "SELECT **db2_value** FROM db2 WHERE db2_field LIKE '" . **$db1_value** . "'";
```

How do I convert `'Maranh&atilde;o'` into `'**Maranhão**'` before comparing?

I've tried several methods, iconv, utf8_encode, and a few others, but they make no difference to the variable. I'm just wondering if I'm taking the right approach to do this.

Appreciate any constructive comments on this.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: `&atilde;` is not UTF-8, it's html entity.

Comment: & atilde; is not an HTML entity :) See the space.

Comment: @ParahatMelayev the space was added by the op *(the space in between is intentional here so you can see the codification)*

Comment: @Esailija That explained the whole thing!! I definitely need to do some studying on this... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert not from `UTF-8` but from `HTML-ENTITIES` into actual value
Luckily mbstring extension has such conversion available:

```
$latin1 = mb_convert_encoding($db1_value, "ISO-8859-1", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```

Here we specify the `HTML-ENTITIES` as the `FROM` charset

Then you can compare `$latin1` to your `$db2_value`.

Comment: Yes but html_entity_decode does not convert string into latin-1 - it will stay as utf-8, and since you are comparing to latin-1 string it's much better to convert your string to latin-1 just to be 100% sure.

Comment: Actually I was being very stupid about the whole thing (sorry, I've never really had to deal with encoding), I realized did not need to decode anything, just convert the HTML-ENTITY into the text I wanted. I got confused because of the collation on both databases. Thanks anyway!